# What does ( his never came from stepping on everyone along the way) mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to improve my English by reading books and i have found this sentence which I coudnt understand.

> **He works hard, as a military police captain so I don't get to see him as much as I want . Ma tells me that his never came from stepping on everyone along the way**

and what does the pronoun **his** for  ? This is the text:

> They were financially stable until Pa turned to gambling. At first, he was good at it and won many times. Then one day he went too far and bet everything on a game his house and all his money. He lost that game and almost lost his family when Ma threatened to **walk out on him** if he did not stop gambling. After that, Pa never played card games again. Now we are all forbidden to play cards or even to bring a deck of cards home. If caught, even I will receive grave punishment from him. Other than his gambling, Pa is everything a good father could be: kind, gentle, and loving. He works hard, as a military police captain so I don’t get to see him as much as I want. Ma tells me that **his** never came from stepping on everyone along the way. Pa never forgot what it was like to be poor, and as a result, he takes time to help many others in need. People truly respect and like him. “Loung is too smart and **clever for people to understand**,” Pa says and winks at me. I beam at him. While I don’t know about the cleverness part, I do know that I am curious about the world—from worms and bugs to chicken fights and the bras Ma hangs in her room.

The last question: what does he mean by **clever for people to understand** ?

Comment: If this was quoted verbatim, you might be better off reading other editions. This version has non-standard spelling, capitalisation and punctuation.

Comment: The meaning that comes across is that "he" arrived at his rank through personal exertion, not at the expense of others.

Comment: Im reading a book called   First They Killed My Father and the writer is not native english . do you think that she used improper English

Comment: It's a style of writing that tries to be informal.

Comment: I had written it since im reading from a book and made some mistake . it was Captain

Comment: But the thing which i cant understand why she used his instead of he when she said his never cam from . and what does never came from mean ?

Comment: In that case, it would be better to [edit] your question to reflect what was actually printed in the book. The "his" might refer to something like "his successes" - the context of the quote should give you more information.

Comment: Have a look at [ellipsis (linguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Comment: By the way, proofreading is considered off-topic on EL&U unless you specify the area of concern. I think [your comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372336/what-does-his-never-came-from-stepping-on-everyone-along-the-way-mean#comment871537_372336) is a valid area of concern. Also, comments are sometimes deleted without notice, but questions and answers are treated with more dignity. I suggest that you [edit] your question to include the note about "his" and quote a larger chunk - perhaps the whole paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. The extra context makes the author's style clearer. Please note that Stack Exchange is intended to be a reference repository, so encourages questions to be focused. Your original question about 'his' is fine, especially with the extended quote. However, asking about other phrases in the same question dilutes the focus. You're also expected to show what you've already found yourself. This avoids 'do my homework' requests, and it helps the community better provide useful answers. Have a look at [this help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "His", as highlighted, looks like an error of some sort.  Possibly the word after "his" was accidentally deleted, possibly there is a missing predecessor, due to a previous line or phrase being deleted.  Possibly simply poor writing, or some sort of dialect.

Comment: I agree. I think they chopped of a *t*. *This* makes more sense than *his*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Step on" is a phrasal verb:

> **step on someone** to treat someone badly, especially because they have less power or importance than you
>   [- Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/step-on)

Imagine yourself trying to climb a ladder that already has many people on it. Some might politely wait for a rung of the ladder to be vacated before stepping on it, but others might simply step on the hand or foot that's already there, seeking to get ahead even if it's at someone else's cost. *Stepping on someone* has the sense of the latter, at least figuratively.